# Is the LDAP protocoll used on clients without Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap

the LDAP protocol is responsible for communication between a client and the Active Directory.

If my client has no connection to a server with Active Directory, does it still use the LDAP protocol for local user queries?

Thanks for your answer.

Best greetings

Answer (score 0):

If your client is Windows: No, the credentials are cached in a registry hive.

If you want more details about authentication in Windows, here is Microsoft's documentation about [Windows credentials management](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/windows-authentication/credentials-processes-in-windows-authentication#BKMK_CachedCredentialsAndValidation)